# Adding users with roles into app registration

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I can see you can create app registrations with graph API but is it possible to add users and roles to an app registration?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question. Are you trying to add users as an 'owner' of the application? What is your scenario?

Comment: We want to create a custom UI that add users to AAD and following add them to an app registration so they can log-in to an application. When you assign users to an app registration you can apply a role. We want to do this from code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to assign a user to that application, in one of the specified app roles, you'll need to set the `appRoleAssignment` on the user . If using Azure AD Graph api , you could use below rest api :

```
https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/users/{username}/appRoleAssignments?api-version={api-version}
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization: Bearer {token}
{
    "id": "RoleID", 
    "principalId":  "UserObjectID", 
    "principalType": "User", 
    "resourceId":  "servicePrincipalID"
}
```

**id**: This is the Id for the Role you are assigning. These Ids can be found in the Application's Manifest. Or you could use below api to get the specific role defined for your application(`appRoles` claim):

```
https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/applications/{ObjectIDOfApplication}?api-version=1.6
```

**principalId** :This is the Obeject Id of the User you are assigning the role to.

**principalType** :If you are assigning this role to a User then this is set to the string `User` .

**resourceId** : Service Principal ID of the application . To get service principal id , you could use below api (`objectId` claim) :

```
https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/servicePrincipals?api-version=1.6&$filter=appId eq 'appid'
```

Answer (score 1):

Application role assignments are available in the **Microsoft Graph** Beta endpoint: see [Update approleassignment](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/approleassignment)

To give you an idea of what could do to add app role assignments to a user, I suggest you look at the [Configure.ps1](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims/blob/master/Configure.ps1#L271) PowerShell script of the [active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims) sample on GitHub, which creates test users of a given role and updates the application registration. This is in PowerShell, but you should be able to adapt it to using MSGraph