# How To Add Users to an App Group and Role with Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a C# .NET MVC Web App on Azure that I've turned Easy Auth on for Azure AD accounts.

I'm trying to add a user to this web app's "Users and Groups" list associated with the App Registration and assign it a Role defined by the associated manifest.

So far I'm able to get the app's manifest (which contains the app roles' info, such as the id and name) with this call made in my controller:

```cs
public JObject GetRoleInfoViaId(string appObjectId)
{
    string accessToken = this.Request.Headers["X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ACCESS-TOKEN"]; // Get Easy Auth Access Token
    var url = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/{appObjectId}"; // MS Graph

    // Call the URL and return the response
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        var response = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
        var json = JObject.Parse(response);

        return json;
    }
}
```

From here I'm stuck. I have no idea how to go about adding a user to the app and/or app role.

If this is not possible in Microsoft Graph yet, I can switch this to Azure AD Graph. It's the functionality I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign a user to that application, in one of the specified app roles, you'll need to set the appRoleAssignment on the user . You can achieve that via Azure AD Graph API . Please refer to [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46396902/5751404) for explanation and API operations .

Comment: I'm also not sure how to convert your example into C#. I'll of course be trying to figure it out myself, but for now I'm stuck. I haven't worked with HTTP calls before so I'm still learning.

Comment: After you acquire access token for Azure AD Graph API with easy auth(change resource to `https://graph.windows.net` when acquiring token) , the rest part is only the simple http request with correct header(Authorization bearer header) . I think you can make that .